# How empting invisible field?

Tags: 8, forms

I'm using this in node add form alter to hide field 'field_obyavlenie_ploschad_uch':

```
$form['field_obyavlenie_ploschad_uch']['#states'] = [
  'invisible' => [
    'select[name="field_obyavlenie_rubrika"]' => ['value' => '4524'],
  ]
];
```

But if user enter any value in this field (before the field was hiding) I see this value in Node view.

I'm trying empty field value, but it not working:

```
$form['field_obyavlenie_ploschad_uch']['#states'] = [
  'empty' => [
    'select[name="field_obyavlenie_rubrika"]' => ['value' => '4524'],
  ]
];
```

How empting invisible field?

Comment: change `select` by `:select` it will work, so instead of `'select[name="field_obyavlenie_rubrika"]'` use `':select[name="field_obyavlenie_rubrika"]'`

Comment: It not working. State "empty" using only for controller field but not for target field.
I don't know how to clear/reset field value if state field is "invisible"

Comment: States are not for emptying (or changing in general) a value in general, they are for controlling display of a field with certain conditions. And "empty" is not a valid state for the element, it's only valid for the remote condition (see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.9.x)